# SlideUp slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

i have this javascript code:

```
var x="#wrapper"
//var xyz;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#about").click(function(){
    if (!(x=="#about")){
        $(x).slideUp("slow",function(){
            $("#aboutus").slideDown("slow");
            });

            x="#aboutus";
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home").click(function(){ 
        if(!(x=="#wrapper")){
        $(x).slideUp("slow", function(){
            $("#wrapper").slideDown("slow");
            });
        dd="#wrapper";
        }
    });
});
```

with this "menu"

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="ul">
    <h6>
                <li id="home" >Home</li >
                <li id="about">About</li >
                <li >performance</li >
                <li >testimonials</li >
                <li >faqs</li >
                <li >forum</li >
                <li onclick="slideUpDown()">Contact  </li >
            </ul>
        </h6>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I must use the the li tags as links and when I click the about "link" the home div must slide up slowly and the about div is supposed to come down slowly.
please help!

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your code, set **x** to **#wrapper** not dd:

```
var x="#wrapper"

//var xyz; 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#about").click(function(){
        if (!(x=="#about")){
            $(x).slideUp("slow",function(){
                $("#aboutus").slideDown("slow");
            });
            x="#aboutus";
        }
    });

    $("#home").click(function(){ 
        if(!(x=="#wrapper")){
            $(x).slideUp("slow", function(){
                $("#wrapper").slideDown("slow");
            });
            x="#wrapper";
        }

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came on this nice one a while ago. It is simple and works.

```
function toggleForm(x) {
        if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
            $('#'+x).slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $('#'+x).slideUp(200);
        }
}
```

Then to call it ...

```
onmousedown="javascript:toggleForm('div_ID');
```

and to not change your URL add this in front on the same call

```
onclick="return false"
```

with this, you can use one script to call as many slid operations as you want. The div to be targeted is the one that has its ID in the call.

EDIT: sorry ... Just noted that it is jQuery, but should not affect anything. I used it where other jQuery did not. So does not seem to conflict anywere.